# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found when running python file

Tags: python, csv, unicode, typeerror, argparse

I have a python script that reads in data from a .csv file and uses it to make mathematical calculation on the data. When I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HW1_PythonTemplate.py", line 120, in <module>
    print ','.join(map(str,calculate(args.data, args.i)))
  File "HW1_PythonTemplate.py", line 56, in calculate
    with open(file, 'r') as csvfile:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found
```

My code looks like:

```
import argparse
import csv
import sys

def calculate( dataFile, ithAttr):


    numObj, minValue, maxValue, mean, stdev, Q1, median, Q3, IQR = [0,"inf","-inf",0,0,0,0,0,0]

    rows = []
    with open(file, 'r') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in csvreader:
            rows.append(row)

    columniStr = [row[ithAttr-1] for row in rows]
    columniFloat = []
    for value in columniStr:
        try:
            columniFloat.append(float(value))
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

In the calculate function, everything past that is just arbitrary math.

My main looks like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='calc')
    parser.add_argument('--i', type=int,
                            help="ith attribute of the dataset (2 <= i <= 29)", 
                            default=5,
                            choices=range(2,30),
                            required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--data", type=str, 
                            help="Location of the dataset file",
                            default="energydata_complete.csv", 
                            required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print ','.join(map(str,calculate(args.data, args.i)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open(file
```

You mis-spelled `dataFile`.

`file` is the built-in Python datatype for file objects, so you're accidentally trying to open a type.

Comment: This is correct, thank you! I was so confused but it works perfectly now